# GitHub shows "Processing updates" on my Pull Request after every push

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Previously, every `git push` to an open Pull Request was shown immediately. It might or might not have triggered CI, but the commit showed up in the "Commits" tab right away.

Now, every time when I push another commit to the Pull Request branch, it doesn't show up immediately, and instead the "Processing updates" loading indicator appears:

[image: the "Processing updates" loading indicator]

This is worrying, because the GitHub interface still allows the Pull Request to be merged, even though some commits are not processed yet.

I haven't changed any configuration though, neither in the repo, nor in my profile.

**What happened? Why the change?**

The "external link" icon refers to the page [**More details provided when a pull request is merged indirectly or is still processing updates**](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-26-more-details-provided-when-a-pull-request-is-merged-indirectly-or-is-still-processing-updates/). The page contains a paragraph [**Pushed commits are still being processed**](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-26-more-details-provided-when-a-pull-request-is-merged-indirectly-or-is-still-processing-updates/#pushed-commits-are-still-being-processed), which might be relevant, but it doesn't have a lot of info:

> [image: Help article paragraph screenshot]

Specifically, it doesn't explain *why* it now "takes longer than usual for [new commits] to be processed and appear in the commit list".

Comment: Could be anything from your repository being bigger to GitHub downgrading its servers in your region.

Comment: my guess its a degradation on GH side. I experience it now as well - more than 5 minutes already. Despite status.github.com is all green, downdetector shows a spike on GH site.

Comment: @walv - same here

Comment: @walv Same here.  2023-11-27 at 2:37 EST time.  Looks like GitHub is having some sort of outage or service degradation.

Comment: Me too, It's been around 20 minutes already

Comment: same here. We are on github enterprise, not sure if related

Comment: Confirmed an issue on GitHub's side https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/66vhjmd266r9

Comment: Same for me. About an hour ago, everything was OK.

Comment: now face this issue

Comment: fixed now on my side

Comment: ... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯​​​​​​​ ...

Comment: I am also facing same problem :( their copilot is making the world difficult I guess :P

Answer (score 2):

> What happened? Why the change?

The GitHub background job servers have more to deal with nowadays (Q4 2023).

You have:

- [Rulesets](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/about-rulesets), introduced:

  - first in [beta in April 2023](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-04-17-introducing-repository-rules-public-beta/)
  - then [in June 2023](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-06-27-repository-rules-public-beta-updates/), with bug fixes like "Branches could not always be created when using commit metadata rules"
  - then in [Oct. 2023](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-10-12-repository-rules-public-beta-history-import-export/)

  The post you mentioned ("[More details provided when a pull request is merged indirectly or is still processing updates](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-26-more-details-provided-when-a-pull-request-is-merged-indirectly-or-is-still-processing-updates/)") from Sept. 2023 does mention:

  > Note: this message only appears when using rulesets.
- Copilot, which can tax those background job servers to process the chat. The [recent "incident with Copilot"](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/fj7v3z6fy7ym) can attest to that.

If the GitHub background job servers have any issue ([as it was the case recently](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/66vhjmd266r9)), any repository with that kind of configuration could remain in that "processing" state indefinitely.

The recent "[Incident with Pull Requests, Issues, Webhooks and Actions](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/66vhjmd266r9)" adds:

> Our background job servers were unable to start because a valid configuration is required at worker start up. As a result, users experienced delays in Pull Requests, Webhooks, Issues, Actions and Projects
>
> Delayed updates to Issues and Pull Requests were applied normally once the changes were rolled back. After the change was rolled back, a large queue of Actions-related jobs built up which included Pull Request, Pull Request review and Pull Request review comment events.